# How to save link list to file with "data" filed as struct

Tags: c, file

I want to save/load linked list to/from a file, but the problem is the data filed in the linked list is struct and it saves the address and not the data.

How can I solve this?

This the link list:

```c
typedef struct LNode
{
    void* data;
    struct LNode* next;
} LNode;

typedef struct
{
    struct  LNode* head, * tail;
    void (*printNode)(void*);
    int (*compare)(void*, void*);
} List;
```

This is the struct in the data filed

```c
struct _Patient
{
    char* name;
    int year;
    Doctor* doctor;
} typedef Patient;
```

This the function I did

```c
void saveList(const char* fileName, const List* list) {
    FILE* f = fopen(fileName, "wb");
    LNode* temp;
    temp = list->head;

    while (temp != NULL) {
        if (f != NULL) {
            fwrite(temp, sizeof(LNode), 1, f);
            //fcloseall();
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? And please add language tag, so people familiar with the language can more easily find your question.

Comment: What output do you expect?